# SQL recursion in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, recursion

I'm reading data from 2 csv using pandas `read_csv`.

Details.csv

```
ID,VALID
P1,Yes
P2,No
P3,Yes
P4,No
```

Relations.csv

```
ParentID,ChildID
P1,C1
P1,C2
C1,C1A
C2,C2A
C1A,C1AA
P2,D1
P2,D2
D2,D2A
D2A,D2AA
P3,C4
P4,C5
```

Now i stored both in separate dataframes. I have to check the ID's from `Details` in `Relationship` and for each `ID` find all level of its children(until no further child). If the ID has `Yes` for VALID column, then all its child should have "VALID" if not then those are "NOT VALID".

Expected output

```
P1,VALID
C1,VALID
C2,VALID
C1A,VALID
C2A,VALID
C1AA,VALID
P2,NOT VALID
D1,NOT VALID
D2,NOT VALID
D2A,NOT VALID
D2AA,NOT VALID
P3,VALID
C4,VALID
P4,NOT VALID
C5,NOT VALID
```

Currently I'm doing this in SQL. I have no idea how to replicate this in python. Are there any functions available in pandas or I have to do with `for` loop. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770595/recursive-sql-cte-query-in-pandas), i have tried something like below but it is not working.

```
import pandas as pd

details = pd.read_csv('C:/Myfolder/Python/Details.csv')
relationship = pd.read_csv('C:/Myfolder/Python/Relationship.csv')

def nlevel(details.id, parent_dict=relationship.ParentID, _cache={0:0}):
if details.id in _cache:
    return _cache[details.id]

return 1+nlevel(parent_dict[details.id],parent_dict)
```

Comment: Is the relation.csv ordered, by this I mean that all the parent-child relation for the same parent in one block: for example, could you have P1,C3 after the row P3,C4, hence P1,C3 is not in the same block than the other P1-child relation?

Comment: Hi @Ben.T. Thanks for you time.  No it is not ordered. It can be any order.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228605/creating-dictionary-of-parent-child-pairs-in-pandas-dataframe) in the meantime someone answers, that addresses your problem while not a full dup

Answer (score 1):

You can do this recursively using a stack. First, put the elements into an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) to simplify traversal, then empty the stack, adding children for each node and storing validity strings in a separate structure. Preserving order, build a result dataframe from the ordered node-validity pairs and dump to CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

details_df = pd.read_csv("Details.csv")
relationship_df = pd.read_csv("Relationship.csv")
order = {k: 1 for k in relationship_df.values.flatten()}
graph = defaultdict(list)
validity = {}

for parent, child in relationship_df.values:
    graph[parent].append(child)

for root, valid in details_df.values:
    stack = [root]

    while stack:
        curr = stack.pop()
        validity[curr] = "VALID" if valid == "Yes" else "NOT VALID"
        stack.extend(graph[curr])

result_df = pd.DataFrame([[x, validity[x]] for x in order])
print(result_df.to_csv(index=False, header=False))
```

Output:

```
P1,VALID
C1,VALID
C2,VALID
C1A,VALID
C2A,VALID
C1AA,VALID
P2,NOT VALID
D1,NOT VALID
D2,NOT VALID
D2A,NOT VALID
D2AA,NOT VALID
P3,VALID
C4,VALID
P4,NOT VALID
C5,NOT VALID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I will check and accept the answer asap.